# Drupal view - new filter criteria resetting from dropdown to autocomplete

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-7

I've created a new filter criteria within a view but want it to show as a drop-down not autocomplete.

I click on settings (next to the name of the new criteria) select Drop down then click Apply (all displays) yet on the preview it shows as an autocomplete filter and on re-clicking the settings of the filter it shows as autocomplete!!?

It seems the filters criteria is resetting to autocomplete from dropdown.

Could this be due to the field I created?

Answer (score 0):

Tried again this morning (problem was yesterday) and seemed to fix itself?

I did initially tick "Show hierarchy in dropdwon" on the extra settings for fiter criterion. Then deselected it later. Not sure if that impacted the proceedings or not.